# How to check similar faces in cognitive face api using persistedFaceIds

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using face api to compare confidence level of 2 images.
i was using face list where i was adding some images and then comparing new image faceid with this list and getting its confidence level.
But as mentioned in https://eastus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395237  faceid is only for 24 hours and expire after that. But persistedFaceIds never get exprire. So can you please suggest how can i use this persistedFaceIds to compare newly added faceid to get its confidence level. We can only create 64 facelists in cognitive (per subscription) and per list contains 1000 records. This is also one limit of this api.
Following is my requirement:
I storing person's images on server. But every image should be unique. Lets suppose if i got an image which is already store on server so i need to ignore that image. 
please suggest how can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FaceList`, I would suggest you to use `PersonGroup`[1][2] instead.

`PersonGroup` support 10,000 persons per person group, it should fits more most common scenario. And you can use the identify [3] api to check whether the image belongs to one specific person.

- [1] https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244
- [2]
  https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c
- [3]
  https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239